# Finding the serial number of a CD

Tags: linux, uniqueidentifier, cd-rom

When I used [this CD cataloging program](http://www.softprime.com/) on Windows, it would identify each CD by a (mostly unique) four-byte serial number, like `376b-4554`. The `dir` command of cmd.exe would show a serial number too.

Now I'm on Linux, and trying to hack my own small CD catalog script. Is there a way to read that serial number from an inserted CD? Or, if not possible, is there any other identifier that I could use for the same purpose? (Don't suggest volume label. I have five CDs labelled "NEW".)

Most programming languages would work, shell commands are okay too.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [freedb](http://www.freedb.org/), there are a lot of programs available that use their DB and identifier to look up CD related information.